# Añadir real="preload" en la carga de etiquetas de google fonts

Tags: wordpress, seo, google-fonts

Esoty utilizando el theme Divi y me gustaría saber como podemos añadir la etiqueta preload cuando añadimos las fuentes de google ya que asi optimizaremos la rapidez de la carga de la web

Comment: `preload` no es una etiqueta sino un valor del atributo `rel`. En la especificación tienes algún ejemplo: https://www.w3.org/TR/preload/, aunque es un borrador así que podría no funcionar correctamente

Comment: Gracias me revisare la documentación